# Assign a Group Variable to a Project Variable in the GitLab UI

Tags: gitlab, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I have a GitLab Project that belongs to a Group. I've defined a number of common variables in the group that I would like to reuse in my projects. I know these variables are inherited by the project, but I would like to be able to re-assign the target group variables from the project as needed.

Is there way to target a group variable from a project? I suspect not, because using the `$VAR_NAME` syntax results in a warning stating the variable cannot be masked (due to the $).

[image]

Comment: With masking GitLab means that it would replace the value with asterisks. I.e. '******'. Which, if it is not able to, like on your screenshot, GitLab warns about. According to the warning the variable may even be expanded; means it would do what you expect it to. Though you need to be aware, that your variables values may be in plaintext in the job log.

Comment: I just tested this, and yes the group variable is expanded. If the group variable is masked, it will remain masked and you can ignore the warning. However, if the group variable is not masked, you cannot mask it at the project level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Masking" in GitLab means that it would replace the value with asterisks. I.e. `*******`. Which, if it is not able to, like on your screenshot, GitLab warns about.

According to the warning the variable will get expanded if such a group level variable exists; means it would do what you expect it to. Though you need to be aware, that your variables values may be in plaintext in the job log.

How it behaves depends on how you configured the group level variable in this case:
If the group level variable is set to be masked, then it will be masked in the expanded project level variable as well.
But you can not mask the expanded variable at the project level, if you did not set the group level variable to be masked in the first place.

A way to work around this uncertainty would be, to directly use the group level variable. Though I can see that this might not always be possible depending on for example differing frameworks used in the projects of a group.